# change innerHTML to form

Tags: javascript, forms

Today I was trying to make the innerHTML of a DIV change to a FORM, but I keep getting the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. I've modified the code to say `changed` and it works fine, but if I try to change it to the following code it gives me that error.

```
document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = '<form method="post" action="all.php?f=mu">
<input name="afterurl" type="hidden" value="<?php $url ?>" />
<input name="preurl" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="newurl" type="text" value="" />
</form>';
```

Any idea how I can get it to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't have text span multiple lines like that in JS. Use string concatenation or put it into one line

```
document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = '<form method="post" action="all.php?f=mu">' +
'<input name="afterurl" type="hidden" value="<?php $url ?>" />' +
'<input name="preurl" type="hidden" value="" />' +
'<input name="newurl" type="text" value="" />' +
'</form>';
```